# How do I manipulate a GET response in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

I have a .Net core Api:

```cs
  var response = new
            {
                Data = data,
                TotalPages = totalPages
            };
            return Ok(response);
        }
```

Data is an IEnumerable of Orders and total pages is an int.
I want to give this response in my Angular app so I have a service

```js
interface Response {
  totalPages: number;
  data: any;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class OrderDataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getOrder(pageNumber: number, pageSize: number): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.get<Response>('http://localhost:5001/api/order/' + pageNumber + '/' + pageSize).pipe(
      map(res => res ),
      );
  }

}
```

My component looks like this:

```js
  constructor(private orderData: OrderDataService) { }

  orders: Order [];
  page = 1;
  pageSize = 10;
  total = 0;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getOrders();
  }

  getOrders(): void {
    this.orderData.getOrder(this.page, this.pageSize)
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.orders = X;
      this.total = Y;

    });

  }
```

I want this.orders to contain the Data part of the response and this.total to contain the totalPages.

Comment: See https://angular.io/guide/http, from there it's just basic JS. Note `.pipe(map(res => res ))` is pointless and if you typed `getOrder` as `Observable<Response>` the compiler would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the answer, you just need to assign it in the subscription:

```
this.order = res.data;
this.total = res.totalPages;
```

Also try to use typescript at it's best utilizing types, you can change your return type of getOrder to `Observable<Response>`.

Also change your interface declaration to:

```
interface Response {
  totalPages: number;
  data: Order[];
}
```

Also I couldn't understand the purpose of the map in the getOrder function, I think it should look like this:

```
 return this.http.get<Response>(`http://localhost:5001/api/order/${pageNumber}/${pageSize});
```